# Would the contents of the AppData folder be retrievable from the hard drive of my old laptop?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, storage, appdata

When my previous laptop's motherboard malfunctioned, I thought I'd still be able to access my old data from my backups, but I couldn't find some of the specific items I was looking for.  The repair shop I took it to put it on the Toshiba 2.5 SATA HDD, which was setup as my D drive.  It includes files that were on the C drive, so I thought my files might be there, but no luck with this either.

One file that I would like back was my Excel personal macro workbook, since I had stored a lot of useful self-written code on there, and it would take a while to reconstruct.  Other than that, I made some changes to XML data used for my programmable mouse, which encompassed several programs.

I used an app called Ultrasearch to look for the items.

Comment: Which directory within AppData exactly? Excel documents are not stored in AppData they would have been saved to Documents within your user’s profile. Depending on how the folder was copied there is a good chance the file wasn’t copied due to a permission issue. How was the copy performed?

Comment: Would the contents of the AppData folder be retrievable from the hard drive of my old laptop?   ........    That seems most unlikely as that is not where Office stores user data.

Comment: I'm assuming the drive is still working. Besides that the answer is "if you can find them". You can do research to figure out where these files are typically stored. You may need to adjust permissions to access them, but that's also a simple and well documented process.

Comment: @Rahmoud I'll have to ask the tech when they open tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: @John the Personal.xlsb macro workbook is stored in  C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Excel\XLStart for Windows 10.  You may be confusing it with the Windows 11 location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try to move the hard disk to another device where there is a slot free and "mount" the disk. If you have bitlocker enabled then it might be more difficult because you need to decrypt using the recovery key.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Would the contents of the AppData folder be retrievable from the hard drive of my old laptop?

A: Yes, assuming the hard disk isn't damaged, and the data hasn't been subsequently overwritten.